# Loop over stdout_lines in Ansible

Tags: python, loops, ansible, jinja2, vmware

I'm querying a vmware ESX box to get the disk IDs using Ansible, however, I'm unable to loop over the stdout_lines which appears to be a standard list.

Here is my query:

```
- name: Collect vSAN disk list
  raw: esxcli storage core device list | grep Devfs 
  delegate_to: esx_box
  register: disk_list

- name: Print disk list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ disk_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

The output for the debug is as follows:

```
ok: 1/1 [esx_box] => {
    "msg": [
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/t10.ATA_____DELLBOSS_VD_____________________________12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/genscsi/naa.12354ABCDEFGHIJK", 
        "   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/genscsi/eui.12354ABCDEFGHIJK"
    ]
}
```

Now, I wanted to loop `disk_list.stdout_lines` as follows

```
- name: Loop over stdout_lines
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ disk_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

But, I do not get any output for the above step. I'm not sure whats happening here. The `stdout_lines` looks to be a proper python list with items in quotes, however the loop with `{{ item }}` simply doesn't loop over.

Comment: Double-check the code. There is no obvious error in the code you posted. This should work.

Comment: Works for me, too.

Comment: Looks like your code is working fine

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I did double check the code, and the loop is not working as intended. Also, did a small test by having a debug print a simple loop and it doesn't work. While, the same works as expected on Fedora. I'm seeing some inconsistencies between Ansible on Fedora 30 vs CentOS 7, despite both being the same version, of course the Python build is different on the CentOS 7

Answer (score 2):

Finally found what the issue was.

In my `ansible.cfg`, I had the `stdout_callback=counter_enabled` and this messes up with the stdout when loops are used. Although the tasks pertaining to loop does work, but doesn't show up in stdout, which confuses the user to assume the loop hasn't executed as intended.

To fix, I had to set `stdout_callback=default`

Answer (score 0):

when using:  with_items  it should work.